# How to Monitor Windows Hosts Network Bandwidth through SNMP?

Tags: windows, networking, central-processing-unit, cacti

I need to monitor Linux and Windows hosts with SNMP and Cacti. I am looking for results in a graph format like MRTG.

I'm looking for the following on the Windows Hosts:

Disk Utilization, CPU load, Network Traffic (Upload and Download) every 30 seconds.

Need take reports PDF format or EXCEL format

Thanks 
Mr.K~

---

On my Distribution Switch make it as mirror port . and monitoring through IPtraf   this is working .I can see the current Bandwidth of the users . Need to Go long way 
as of now configured only TCP traffic .

Working and working

Thanks 
Mr.K~

Comment: Cleaned up question - Cacti creates graphs just like MRTG does. The tool Cacti uses to make it's graphs is actually an evolution from what was behind MRTG. Don't understand what you mean by take reports in PDF or Excel - can you clarify?

Comment: All the monthly reports i need in graph format thats should be in Excel or PDF format

Comment: It would be polite to accept the answer to this question, now that it looks like it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

Install the SNMP service from Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs > Windows Setup.

Then go under Administrative Tools > Services, and right click the "SNMP Service", go to Properties, and there are a few tabs there to configure your SNMP community name, set access control, etc.

Once this is done then you can query hard disk/network traffic/CPU, etc from your monitoring utility via SNMP.

Comment: Accepted fr now ..
i did :) 

Next Cacti :)

Comment: a word of caution: a 1Gbps >= network interface can't be reliably monitored on Windows via SNMP because Windows lacks 64-bit counters and a 32-bit quickly overflows. http://serverfault.com/questions/205785/windows-network-snmp-traffic-overflow